# With Rails + Devise + Pundit, how to give signed-in users a "public preview" view of their profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

The `show` method for a user's profile page uses typical pundit policies to display/hide user-specific actions (such as editing) based on whether the page owner is signed in.

So the show view for example contains:

```
- if policy(@user).edit?
  = link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(@user)
```

I'd also like to add a link that shows the signed-in user in a new tab what the page would look like to a public user (not signed in), ideally without creating a whole new view, perhaps something adding a 'public' url param to the show url, like

```
- if policy(@user).edit?
  = link_to "Show Public Version", user_path(@user, public_view: 'yes'), target: "_blank"
```

Of course it's easy to brute-force by changing all the policy-based logic in the view from

```
- if policy(@user).edit?
```

to

```
- if policy(@user).edit? && !@public_view
```

(where @public_view is set true in the controller when params[:public] == 'yes')

But I expect there is a much DRYer and cleaner approach, perhaps some modification to the actual UserPolicy methods?